# Laptop locks up on cloned SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just cloned my HDD to a new  SSD.  I expected to plug in the new SSD and be off to happy computing.  I used an external USB SATA jig for the new SSD.
After I booted, the laptop operated fast  and there were two issues.  First I  immediately got an error from QuickBooks that the license had an issue.  Secondly, if the pc went to screen saver, it locked up.  I had to restart  it each time to get it to run.

Does anyone have an idea why this would happen.  I have always assumed that  a disc clone was golden -- there should never be issues.  I just cloned a HDD to a SSD for a Mac last week and it worked flawlessly.  Any help would be appreciated.   I am on Windows 10 Pro and am on version 1803.

I used Acronis True Image Home 2015 and the MBR partition. In hindsight, my original HDD was UEFI.  Might this have created the issues I am seeing?

Comment: What software did you use to clone it? Was the original HDD formatted with an MBR table or with GPT (check with diskpart)? Is the SSD formatted with an MBR table or with GPT? Please, as is standard here, click on `edit` at left above to add your answers to these questions to your original post, so prospective helpers do not need to weed through commends such as this.

Comment: If you changed the partition format than you didn’t actually clone the drive. So, yes, the first thing to try is to re-clone the drive exactly.

Comment: I checked and both are Basic /  MBR.

Answer (score 0):

If we change the HDD to a new cloned SSD, we need to reactivate the operating system in cloned SSD, we need to check if the operating system from cloned SSD is activated, if no, we reactivate the operating system by the following two way:

1. Retail activate way: [Microsoft Licensing Activation Centers worldwide telephone numbers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/existing-customer/activation-centers.aspx)
2. OEM(Original Equipment Manufacturer) activate way: OEM activation is bound to the motherboard. As long as the motherboard is not replaced, it does not need to be reactivated. If we change hard disk, it should be activated automatically, if it is not activated now, we can consult the laptop vendor to reactivate.

Probably because of the cloned operating system, online updates after first normal startup caused some settings and policy changes.

Turn off hibernation and restart the laptop.

1. Search for **cmd**. In the search results list, right-click **Command Prompt**, and then click **Run as Administrator**.
2. At the command prompt, type **powercfg.exe /hibernate off**, and then press **Enter**.
3. Restart the laptop.

We try to turn off screen saver, then see if the laptop locks up on cloned SSD.

1. The laptop does not lock up on cloned SSD by turning off screen saver, we can turn off screen saver in **Setting** to fix the issue.
2. The laptop locks up on cloned SSD by turning off screen saver, we can turn off lock screen or adjust the duration of the lock screen.

If the above does not work, we try to  re-clone the SSD according to the following article: [How to Upgrade Your Laptop’s Hard Drive to an SSD](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/ssd-upgrade-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my case, I did not have to re-activate Windows. I have cloned my drive twice and both times Widows was already activated.

I did take your advice and disable screen saver before the clone. This solved the lockup issue. I also ran CHKDSK and SFC before I cloned the drive the second time. The cloned drive worked fine except Quickbooks had a license missing error.

Comment: When I reinstalled the old HDD into the laptop, QB opened just fine. Intuit wants me to reregister the product which  I cannot do as my product was never registered by me. I bought QB Pro 2015 from a 3rd party and just discovered that they never gave me the registration info. In hindsight, the $50 I saved was not worth it. I will be purchasing QB Pro 2018 today. Live and learn.